# I can't find CRS EPSG 27700 in version 3.6.0

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have tried to use the filter element in the Project properties menu to find EPSG 27700 with no success.

Any suggestions please for converting to British National Grid

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure how did you search for the EPSG 27700, but it exists. I went to `Project -> Properties -> CRS` and it is there:

[image]

I am using 3.6.0-Noosa.